# How can I pass along node-related data in a complex query when I'm collecting, combining, and unwinding nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that starts from a specific :Person, and, using a few different methods of relationship traversal, gathers all of those interested :Person nodes together (distinctly), and returns a common data set for each of those :Persons.

One of those pieces of data reflects the mode or types of that relationship, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to set a flag indicating that relationship as I discover :Persons in that relationship, and preserve that flag even as I collect, add, unwind, and make distinct those :Persons.

As a simplified example, I have direct :Friend relationships to :Persons, those are easy to gather up. I also have a :WorkPlace node that a person :WorksAt. I use this to find my coworkers, who are :Persons who also :WorksAt that same :WorkPlace.

I want a way to combine both results of :Persons to get a distinct set (all of my friends combined with all of my coworkers, without duplicates if a :Person is both a friend and a coworker). Union won't help me, as that doesn't allow post-processing of results. Instead, I separately collect both sets of :Persons from the subqueries, add them together so they're all in the same list, unwind them, and get the distinct rows. This already works for me.

At this point I now have all the :Persons I am interested in, and I can start subqueries to get other nodes of data that they may have that I want to include with each output Person row.

However, one of those pieces of data is a boolean if that :Person is a coworker. To get this, I do a repeat of a part of one of those gathering queries to check that relationship (does this :Person work at the same :WorkPlace I do?) and store it as a boolean for output.

This works just fine...but I feel like I'm doing extra work, that there should be some way to flag and preserve an isCoworker boolean when I do the initial match and find those coworkers the first time. The ideal would be to attach this flag into the node somewhere, so it might survive the collects() and unwinds...but I don't know how to do that. Even if I COULD do that, I don't think it would survive the DISTINCT operator (for the same :Person being discovered as a :Friend, that flag won't be present, and I might have ANOTHER flag, isFriend, that I want to combine as well so the resulting :Person will have both flags present). Likewise, I don't think such a flag created separately could survive all of those operations either.

Has anyone else encountered (and hopefully solved) this sort of problem?

EDIT:

Adding a simplified version of my query.

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:777})
WITH me
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Friend]-(friend:Person)
WITH me, collect(friend) AS friends
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:WorksAt]->[:WorkPlace]<-[:WorksAt]-(coworker:Person)
WHERE coworker <> me
WITH friends + collect(coworkers) AS everyone
UNWIND everyone AS acquaintance
WITH DISTINCT acquaintance
// ...
WITH acquaintance
OPTIONAL MATCH (meAgain:Person{id:777})-[:WorksAt]->(:WorkPlace)<-[r:WorksAt]-(acquaintance)
WITH meAgain, acquaintance, r IS NOT NULL AS isCoworker
OPTIONAL MATCH (meAgain)-[r:Friend]-(acquaintance)
RETURN acquaintance, isCoworker, r IS NOT NULL AS isFriend
```

Again, this is simplified. At the ... I'm gathering data common for any :Person object, and just omitting passing and usage and output of that data in the rest of the query as it isn't related to my problem. Also there are several ways to gather :Persons, not just these two simple examples.

It's the OPTIONAL MATCHES that I'm trying to optimize out by somehow holding onto similar flags (isCoworker, isFriend) but created at the time I matched to these :Persons. Those flags have to be able to survive the collects(), list addition, unwinding, and distinct operations.

Comment: I added a simplified version of the query, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep a second collection being the coworkers and do a check with `IN` to get your boolean where you need it.

As an example modified query :

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:777})
WITH me
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Friend]-(friend:Person)
WITH me, collect(friend) AS friends
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:WorksAt]->[:WorkPlace]<-[:WorksAt]-(coworker:Person)
WHERE coworker <> me
WITH friends, friends + collect(coworkers) AS everyone, collect(distinct coworker) AS coworkers
UNWIND everyone AS acquaintance
WITH DISTINCT acquaintance, coworkers, friends
// ...
WITH acquaintance, coworkers, friends
WITH meAgain, acquaintance, acquaintance IN coworkers AS isCoworker
RETURN acquaintance, isCoworker, acquaintance IN friends AS isFriend
```

Comment: Looks good, I'll give that a go! Glad it's a simple solution, thanks!